# Como fazer uma subquery no Laravel com base nessas informações?

Tags: laravel

Tenho as tabelas:

**notifications:**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**users:**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

... E tenho o seguinte **código** que está no meu **controller**:

```
public function allRelations($internalClientId)
{              
        
  $internalClient = InternalClient::find($internalClientId);
        
  if(empty($internalClient))
  {
     return response()->json(['error' => 'Internal Client not found!'], 404);
  } 

  $notifications = InternalClient::join('notifications', 'notifications.internal_client_id','=','internal_client_id')         
  ->select(                                               
           'notifications.id AS notification_id',                                        
           'notifications.from_user_id AS from_user_id',                                       
           'notifications.to_user_id AS to_user_id', 
           'notifications.title AS notification_title', 
           'notifications.message AS notification_message',
           'notifications.checked AS notification_checked'
          )                                                          
          ->where('internal_client_id',$internalClientId) 
          ->groupBy('notifications.id')     
          ->get();

   return response()->json($notifications, 201);
}
```

**No momento esse código me retorna isso:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Até ai tudo bem. Só que eu gostaria de retornar o '**name**' (que está na tabela **users**) correspondentes aqueles **ID's** que estão nos campos **from_user_id** e **to_user_id** na tabela **notifications** (que são foreign key de usuários da tabela **users**). Acredito que para isso será necessário fazer uma **subquery**. Porém nunca fiz isso no Laravel.

Alguém poderia me ajudar ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver utilizando o **raw** da classe **DB**.

Importei a classe no topo do arquivo assim:
*use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB; //Chamando a classe DB*

**E o código do método ficou assim:**

```
public function allRelations($internalClientId)
{              
        
   $internalClient = InternalClient::find($internalClientId);
        
   if(empty($internalClient))
   {
      return response()->json(['error' => 'Internal Client not found!'], 404);
   } 

   $notifications = InternalClient::join('notifications', 'notifications.internal_client_id','=','internal_client_id')          
   ->select(                                               
             'notifications.id AS notification_id',                                        
             'notifications.from_user_id AS from_user_id', 
              DB::raw("(SELECT name FROM users WHERE id = from_user_id) AS from_user_name"),           
              'notifications.to_user_id AS to_user_id', 
              DB::raw("(SELECT name FROM users WHERE id = to_user_id) AS to_user_name"),
              'notifications.title AS notification_title', 
              'notifications.message AS notification_message',
              'notifications.checked AS notification_checked'                                         
            )                                                          
            ->where('internal_client_id',$internalClientId) 
            ->groupBy('notifications.id')     
            ->get();

   return response()->json($notifications, 201);
}
```

**O retorno ficou assim:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Apesar de eu achar que tenha ficado meio feio (e saído [acho eu] um pouco da premissa do Laravel), foi exatamente o que eu estava precisando. Espero que possa ajudar a quem mais precisar!